# Update in Firestore is causing infinite loop

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to set up a counter in Firestore using Angular 4 that updates whenever a person clicks on a particular button. Clicking the button does update the counter but it starts an infinite loop. The only way to stop it is to comment out the line which does not help since I need to update the counter each time I decide to click that button. Here is the code.

```
addFoodToCart(uid: string, email: string, item: Goods)
  {
    this.getUserInDB(email).doc(uid).valueChanges().subscribe(a =>
    {
      this.getUserInDB(email).doc(uid).collection('cart').add(item);
      this.getUserInDB(email).doc(uid).update({'food': ++a['food'], 'technology': 0, 'email': email});
    });
  }﻿
```

As you can see I am also adding an item to the same database but I commented that part out too and it still causes the infinite loop in the db. Any reason why this happens and how to fix it? I am also using Google Chrome as my web browser for development. Don't know if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to test this, but you can add the `take()` operator to unwire the subscription after a single return value:

```
addFoodToCart(uid: string, email: string, item: Goods)
{
    this.getUserInDB(email).doc(uid).valueChanges().take(1).subscribe(a =>
    {
        this.getUserInDB(email).doc(uid).collection('cart').add(item);
        this.getUserInDB(email).doc(uid).update({'food': ++a['food'], 'technology': 0, 'email': email});
    });
}
```

Assuming you have a longer-lived subscription to this document wired up somewhere else then the update should be reflected automatically.

*Note, depending on what your app does you may need to await these calls (or handle the promises in some other way*

Comment: Would you place the take operator after the subscription. I tried doing that and it is saying that take() does not exist on type Subscription

Comment: Yeah you will need to import the operator at the top of your file. Check out the angular or rxjs docs to see the syntax (sorry on my phone it I'd try to provide it for you).

Comment: I have tried doing the way you have suggested and it still is casing that issue. What I have noticed though is that it seems to execute when I change the value in firestore so maybe its executing based off the change in the value in the firestore database.